Closing times of terminal windows
I ran some processes on my ubuntu 22.04 terminal ( by opening multiple terminal windows). But after a few hours when I logged on I found that all the terminal sessions were closed. My question is : How can I know the closing times of the terminal sessions ?

gnome-terminal shouldn't close on its own for no reason. It could have exceeded some system resources or could have crashed due to a programming error or maybe even a hardware failure. (Note: a single process handles all the gnome-terminal windows; if one crashes then all crash). Check the system logs (including journalctl) for messages about a possible crash or OOM killer or alike. Other than that I'm afraid you're out of luck. [By the way, what Ubuntu version? Please update your question with this info.]

Also... What do you mean by "logged on"? You didn't log out of your graphical desktop environment, did you? That closes all the windows (not just the terminals). I assume you meant you locked your screen and then returned to the computer and unlocked it; correct?

@egmont This is ubuntu 22.04. And by logging out and logging on I mean locking and unlocking the screen.
